# How to distinguish pages created by woocommerce?

Tags: posts, categories, loop, woocommerce-offtopic, pages

I am working on a theme and I have come to a situation when I need to distinguish the pages that are created by the *Woocommerce* plugin (e.g Shop, Cart, etc.).

So far I've installed [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/post-tags-and-categories-for-pages/) which adds tags and categories to pages and categorized each Woocommerce page as `woocommerce`.

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks.

Comment: All pages related to woocommerce have as body tag "woocommerce" (in front end) and some other related body tags too (that are useful for CSS and javascript). For PHP, Themers (or plugin developers) use the dedicated [WooCommerce conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) that will allow you to target any desired WooCommerce page or end points too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [conditional tags](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/conditional-tags/) or function [`wc_get_page_id('page_name')`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/useful-functions/#section-2), where `page_name` can be: '*myaccount*', '*shop*', '*cart*', '*checkout*', etc.

For example:
Using `is_cart()` you can check whether the current page is a cart page.
Using `wc_get_page_id( 'cart' );` you will receive ID of cart page.

Which way is more suitable for your code you have to decide for yourself. Some conditional tags ( like `is_checkout()`, `is_cart()` ) are based on `wc_get_page_id()`.